# Python Indenting (Tabs / Spacing Error)

Tags: python, indentation

I have made a 'battleship' program via Python and decided to structure my code (as previously it was messy but worked fine). However whenever I run my code it now pops up with an indentation error:

```
"File "python", line 29
guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"
```

I searched around and realized I had used some spaces as well as tabs so I switched it purely to tabs (indent by 4 spaces). However the problem still persisted and I don't understand why. Is anyone able to share why this could be?

```
from random import randint
board = []
turn = 0
def print_board(board):
   for row in board:
       print " ".join(row)
def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

#Start Battleship Functionality Here
print "Let's play Battleship!"
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
    print_board(board)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col


for turn in range(4):
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
    print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
    print "Turn", turn + 1
elif (board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
    print "You guessed that one already."
    print "Turn", turn + 1
elif guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
    print_board(board)
    break
elif turn == 3:
    print "Game Over"
else:
    print "You missed my battleship!"
    board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
    print "Turn", turn + 1
    print_board(board)
```

Comment: Aside: The common standard for Python is to use spaces exclusively. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces Also, the code you've pasted above seems to be a mix of spaces and tabs.

Comment: Oh thanks for that Rob! Would you have any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: Probably because you still have a mix of tabs and spaces.

Comment: I ran your code and re-indented the problem line and it ran fine

Comment: Also, watch out when you are re-indenting stuff because I think all those if statements need to be forward one level

Comment: Thank you everyone. As per Carlos Suggestion, I had re-indented my code via the IF statement in my for loop and now everything runs smoothly :)

Thank you stack exchange! Always so quick to help :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the For Statement - because my IF was not indented properly underneath the for loop the indentation levels did not match. Correcting it to this resulted in the program running smoothly.

```
    for turn in range(4):
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
            print "Turn", turn + 1
            etc....
```

Thanks for everyones input!